# c++ related program........ and its about the matrix operations (symetric)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 4;
int main()
{
    int m[ROWS][COLS];
    bool ss;
    int c, r, mt[COLS][ROWS];
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            cout << "\t";
            cout << "x[" << r << "][" << c << "];";
            cin >> m[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
        for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
            mt[c][r] = m[r][c];
    }
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            cout << "\t" << m[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl
         << endl
         << endl;
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            cout << "\t" << mt[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl
         << endl
         << endl;
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            if (m[r][c] == mt[r][c])
                ss = true;
            else {
                ss = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (ss)
        cout << "symetric" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not symetric" << endl;
}
```

This program shows the whether the given matrix is symmetric or not. But it is not showing a correct output. In all cases the program shows the matrix is symmetric (whether it is symmetric or not). How can i resolve this error????

Comment: You can debug the code, understand the reason why you get the incorrect output, and then fix your code according to what you've found.

Comment: Using UPPERCSE identifiers for const variables is an anti-pattern, you better get rid of this bad habit.

Comment: BTW, you probably need to initialize `ss` to either `true` or `false`, and break outside the loop once you set this variable to the opposite value. Since it's a "loop inside loop" that you're dealing with, I recommend that you implement it in a separate function, and `return` immediately after changing `ss` (or even simpler - get rid of this variable and just return the result).

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation, the value of `ss` is simply the value of the expression:

```
m[ROWS-1][COLS-1] == m[ROWS-1][COLS-1]
```

This is because you just continue updating `ss` even after you set it to `false`.

In order to correct this logic, define a standalone function to determine whether or not the matrix is symmetric:

```
bool isSymmetric(int m[ROWS][COLS]) {
    for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) {
            if (m[r][c] != mt[r][c])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And call it from your `main` function:

```
bool ss = isSymmetric(m);
```

P.S.: God knows why you chose to replicate this matrix as `m` and `mt`...